# iOS Phonegap: Changing orientation during splash/loading

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation, cordova-2.0.0

Nowadays, I am working on a iOS project formed with Phonegap 2.0 and jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and I am having a serious issue with orientation changes.

The problem is the screen size proportions after the orientation changes that you make during loading.

After loading completes orientation works without any problem if I didn't change the orientation during loading.

If I change the orientation during the launch/loading of the application than it starts acting weird! like giving white spaces near the screen etc. Orientation is completely start acting weird from that point which pushes me to restart the app.

Did some one face the same problem?